# It keeps showing "TypeError: update() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to code a game with Python, but it keeps showing the error "TypeError: update() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given". I have checked multiple forums including stackoverflow multiple times, but all of them were saying that the error occurs when we forget a 'self' argument. However, that is not my case.

Below, you can see my `tiles.py` file. It shows the `Tile` class.

```
import pygame
class Tile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,pos,size):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((size,size))
        self.image.fill('grey')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = pos)
    def update(self,x_shift):
        self.rect.x += x_shift
```

As you can see, both the `__init__()` and the `update()` functions has the self argument. When I run the update part in `level.py`:

```
import pygame
from tiles import Tile
from settings import tile_size
from player import Player

class Level:
    def __init__(self,level_data,surface):
        self.display_surface = surface
        self.setup_level(level_data)
        self.world_shift = 0
    def setup_level(self,layout):
        self.tiles = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.player = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle()
        for row_index,row in enumerate(layout):
            for col_index,cell in enumerate(row):
                x = col_index * tile_size
                y = row_index * tile_size
                if cell == 'X':
                    tile = Tile((x,y),tile_size)
                    self.tiles.add(tile)
                if cell == 'P':
                    player_sprite = Player((x,y))
                    self.tiles.add(player_sprite)
    def run(self):
        #level tiles
        self.tiles.update(self.world_shift)
        self.tiles.draw(self.display_surface)
        #player
        self.player.update()
        self.player.draw(self.display_surface)
```

The `run` function's `self.tiles.update(self.world_shift)`, as you can see, also has an argument in it, which is the `x_shift` argument. However, when I run the `run` function in my `main.py` file:

```
import pygame, sys
from settings import *
from level import Level

#Setup
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
level = Level(level_map,screen)
pygame.display.set_caption('Pirates Run')

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    
    screen.fill('black')
    level.run()

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

When I have run the code, the only output I get is a black screen that appears for less than a second and then closes, and then an error that looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\Blazel\Pirates Run\code\main.py", line 19, in <module>
level.run()
File "c:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\Blazel\Pirates Run\code\level.py", line 26, in run    
self.tiles.update(self.world_shift)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 531, in update
sprite.update(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: update() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Please help me solve this problem! Thanks!

Comment: `self.tiles` is a `pygame.sprite.Group()`, not an instance of `Tile`.

Comment: So what should I do/edit in my code to make it work? @martineau

Comment: @Rabbid76: I knew there was more to the problem than what I mentioned. Was about to log-off and didn't have time to write a proper answer like yours — so just wanted to at least leave the OP a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First some basics:

[`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw) and [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update) are methods which are provided by `pygame.sprite.Group`.

The latter delegates to the `update` method of the contained [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`s](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) — you have to implement the method. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update):

> Calls the `update()` method on all Sprites in the Group. [...]

The former uses the `image` and `rect` attributes of the contained `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s to draw the objects — you have to ensure that the `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s have the required attributes. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw):

> Draws the contained Sprites to the Surface argument. This uses the `Sprite.image` attribute for the source surface, and `Sprite.rect`. [...]

---

You add `player_sprite` to the `self.tiles` Group.

> ```py
> self.tiles.add(player_sprite)
> ```

The `Tile` object has an update methode:

> ```py
> def update(self,x_shift):
> ```

The `Player` object has an `update` method with a different argument list. This causes the error.
Do not add `player_sprite` to `tiles`, but create a separate *Group* for the player to solve the issue (e.g. [`pygame.sprite.GroupSingle`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html)).